# Version 14.04 crashes too often

Tags: xorg, firefox

I just did the upgrade from version 12.04 to 14.04 and immediately had some problems.

Whenever I try to open certain webpages using Firefox or Chrome, the screen just freezes. Mouse and keyboard are not responding and shortly after that system automatically logs out.

It's especially problematic with Firefox. Most of the time it freezes right after the launch.

Couple of other programs I have used so far seem to work fine.

I examined the error messages and it seems that there is something going on with Xorg. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

So far I've noticed that only the Firefox and Chrome are causing the crash (haven't tested the Opera yet). All the other applications (termial, gedit, Virtualbox, qFTP etc...) seem to run smoothly.

I tried to remove the Firefox and install it again, but it didn't solve the problem.

On one occasion, when the crash happened, similar message was shown on the screen:

```
INFO: task Xorg:2746 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

So I'm not sure whether or not the Xorg is responsible.

Comment: What do you mean by "version 14.04 crashes"?  What are "couple of other programs"? What commands do you invoke? What error messages do you see?

Comment: Is your graphics driver NVIDIA?

Comment: No, it does not seem to be NVIDIA: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03) 00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)`

Answer (score 0):

Use command of "software-properties-gtk -open-tab=4" to change the your graphic card driver (called as restricted drivers)

Comment: I did as you suggested, but there was no info about graphics card drivers.

Comment: That mean you don't have a independent graphic card(eg. nvidia or ati etc). As per the above info, you are using the intel integrated graphic card, the result you are having is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below command to removing the adobe flash plugin and see if the change can help.
"sudo apt-get purge  flashplugin-installer"

Comment: It followed your advice, but nothing changed.

Answer (score -1):

`rm -fr ~/.mozilla` and then try run `firefox` again!

~/.mozilla is firefox user data folder including personal input info and your own plugins, removing will let you run firefox from zero configuration, just like you run firefox at first time

Comment: You should probably explain why this should help, and what the consequences are -- this deletes personal information, possibly including stored passwords, from your home directory.